# Yii - Move Css to end of body

Tags: css, yii

To try and increase the page insight score for my website I am trying to move the css to the bottom so i can inline the critical CSS. The problem I am having is that the css is included using the following method

```
    $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
    $cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/styles.css');
```

The problem with this is that unlike the similar function that includes javascript there is no way to change the position from the head. Any one know how I could do this?

Comment: css should be in head tag. why because if you load css end of the page then your webpage will break until browser gets load css.

Comment: still you want to do this. inside your layout/main.php add direct link tag with src url.

Comment: As i mention in my question I will be inlining the critical CSS so the page will look fine until the css is loaded. This is to prevent render blocking. I could just stick them in main.php but not the greatest way to do it really